# Custom Bindings in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-5, knockout-3.0

I just started out with KnockoutJS and ran into a problem with custom bindings. Im assigning an observable to the custom binding and change that observable through an input field. Another text field already reacts to changes but somehow the update doesnt get triggered.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.someBinding = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    console.log("B");
  }
}

function myModel() {
  this.lastname = ko.observable("name");
}

ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

...

```
<p data-bind="text: lastname"></p>
<input data-bind="value: lastname" />
<p data-bind="someBinding: lastname" ></p>
```

https://jsbin.com/kupitepaxe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Please use on-site Stack Snippets instead of off-site JSBin. The snippet editor is available via Ctrl+M or the `[<>]` toolbar button. [Here's how to do a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because you never access the observable within the binding, and so KO doesn't think you need that observable.

Just access it, e.g.:

```
var currentValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

Normally, you would have done that as part of your binding handler because normally you need the value, but your initial test didn't do it, which is why you didn't get your expected result.

Live Example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.someBinding = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    console.log("B");
    ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  }
}

function myModel() {
  this.lastname = ko.observable("name");
}

ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

```html
<p data-bind="text: lastname"></p>
<input data-bind="value: lastname" />
<p data-bind="someBinding: lastname" ></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that you have to leave the input field above to see your binding handler update, since KO's default is to only update on the `change` event (you can make it more proactive with [`, valueUpdate: 'input change'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)).